# trouble with my pom.xml, *Disclaimer, first time using maven. I'm trying to add dependencies to my pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

When i run my project I get:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> C:\Users\Anubhav\Desktop\QRDemo\Quote.png (The system cannot find the
> path specified)

Here is my pom.xml code:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
   4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>QRCode</groupId>
      <artifactId>QRCode</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>  
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>  
            <version>3.3.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>  
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>  
            <version>3.3.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
      </dependencies>
       <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>16</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

I'm completely lost

Comment: It has nothing to do with `pom.xml`, but with you accessing a File that doesn't exist.

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Anubhav\Desktop\QRDemo\Quote.png` exist on your computer?

Comment: The code was copy and pasted, just researching QR codes. So I guess i need to create a .png file and redirect it to there, for example, the copied code from the main class is //path where we want to get QR Code  
String path = "C:\\Users\\Anubhav\\Desktop\\QRDemo\\Quote.png";

Comment: First if you use Maven you should follow conventions which means directory structure should be kept as it... That means remove `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`. Furthermore if you like to put your result somewhere you need to let do that your application. Maven is a build tool..